# How to combine multiple tables into one table in Big Query?

Tags: google-bigquery, create-table

I'm trying to combine a couple of tables (i.e., 1 created able from Sep - Nov and another created table from Dec - Jan) into 1 comprehensive table of all of them in Big Query.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use UNION ALL to combine queries, so you just query each table.

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM sep_nov_table

UNION ALL

SELECT
  *
FROM dec_jan_table
```